# Hierarchy of Mathematics Breakdown

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can you provide me with a hierarchical breakdown on Discrete Math as it applies to computer science? By this I mean a breakdown on topics that fall under the study of discrete numbers, specifically those that apply to computer science.

I understand that discrete math focuses on noncontinuous numbers such as integers, statements of logic, and graphs. But I don't really understand any practical examples of how these apply... Well statements of logic make sense in programming with if/then/and/or etc, but i'm not sure about the rest.

I really just need someone smart to talk too... any takers?

**Background:** I am starting on a course in computer science that involves programming, networking, etc.

The problem is this course has a very high attrition rate, specifically in its mathematics portion and I only have a few weeks to study before starting the course, which I'll be tested on throughout. I am taking this course for work and all I've been told is to focus on "Discrete Math, Logic, Knights and Knaves"?

As for my own background I feel strong on the actual computer science portion, however I finished highschool with a GED and did terrible in math when I was there... I know this post was extremely vague, terribly worded and will likely be crucified. But I honestly don't know how to ask this question any better and I truly am limited on my knowledge of the upcoming course. I would greatly appreciate any resources or help that you can Offer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im currently in my second year of Computer Science in England.
The most helpful discrete math will be:

- a good understanding of permutation and combinatorics
- Set theory
- propositional logic

It would be beneficial that you also understand how to give some basic proofs involving those.  Im currently working through this book and recommend it:
Discrete and Combinatorial Mathematics by Ralph Grimaldi.
Since you seem confident in the programming part, I'm assuming you have good logical reasoning, which is the most important thing. Have a look at this website: https://projecteuler.net
The problems get hard quick, but you should be able to do the first 2 fairly easily. I haven't gotten very far either, it contains a lot of number theory.