# Detailed Hierarchy of Mathematics (From Beginners to Advanced)

Tags: soft-question, definition

What is the most generic hierarchy of learning Mathematics? For example, a more descriptive version of the following:

> - Numbers
> - Pre-Algebra
> - Basic Algebra
> - Intemediate Algebra
> - Advanced Algebra
> - Precalculus
> - Trigonometry
> - Calculus I
> - Calculus II
> - So on...

I have found a few questions with a similar title that fails to precisely answer the question.

- [Hierarchy of Mathematics Breakdown](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068514/hierarchy-of-mathematics-breakdown)
- [What is the structural hierarchy in mathematics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1767320/what-is-the-structural-hierarchy-in-mathematics)
- [Is there a conceptual hierarchy in mathematics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3776454/is-there-a-conceptual-hierarchy-in-mathematics)

I haven't found a single page which addresses the hierarchy other than this [Quora answer](https://qr.ae/pNMW1b). Can someone fix the hierarchy and add more topics to it. Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't see geometry, sets, or logic in your list of subjects. Also, some things are learned in parallel. I think it also depends on the curriculum. Different states/countries might have slight variations. Plus, it's not clear what's Advanced algebra for example. Is that group theory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try Mathematics Subject Classification at AMS.

See: https://mathscinet.ams.org/msc/msc2010.html

PDF of 2020 classification: https://mathscinet.ams.org/msc/pdfs/classifications2020.pdf